# :checked-functionality for li-element

Tags: css

how can I simulate the behaviour of :checked for other elements then input-elements, like - this doesn't work of course, just for demonstrating purposes - for example here:

```
li{ background:red;}
li:checked{
background:orange;}
```

I actually want to use a plain css-solution and need to update the style of a li-element if this was clicked (`:active` does that, but solely for the moment of clicking it, I need it to keep the updated style as long as it's clicked again)

Thanks

Comment: You should show the code structure of your HTML, it'll be easy for you as well as for the others to provide solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way, for a pure CSS solution, is to use a `label` with a `checkbox`, and to make that `checkbox` hidden:

```css
input{
    display:none;
}

label{
    color: blue;
}

input:checked + label{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
        <label for="cb">click</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
        <label for="foo">click</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bar">
        <label for="bar">click</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtLa8wdj/2/)

---

Or, if you want to change some styles to `li`, then:

```css
input{
    display:none;
}

li{
    color: blue;
}

input:checked + ul>li{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="cb">click</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtLa8wdj/1/)

---

However, if you have multiple `checkboxes`, and you want to have them outside the `ul` (not in the same `li`), then it's a little bit complicated:

```css
input{
    display:none;
}

li{
    color: blue;
}

#cb:checked + input + input + ul>li:first-child{
    color: red;
}

#foo:checked + input + ul>li:nth-child(2){
    color: red;
}

#bar:checked + ul>li:nth-child(3){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<input type="checkbox" id="bar">
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="cb">click</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="foo">click</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="bar">click</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtLa8wdj/3/)

Note: some answers put `input[type=checkbox]` as a direct child of `ul`, which **is not valid** - only `li` can be a direct child of `ul/ol`.

Comment: Why don't you add multiple checkboxes in demo

Comment: @Tushar didn't think it was needed. Will update the answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can track a clicked/non-clicked state in pure CSS on anything but a checkbox. I believe that your best course of action is to hook up a JS event listener to toggle a class on the list item on click.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by having an invisible checkbox before the list item and have the contents of the list item acting as the label for that invisible checkbox.

#### css

```
li { background:red; }
*:checked + li { background:orange; }
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

#### html

```
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="some_name"/>
<li><label for="some_name">The list item.</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanto try this:

```css
.my-ul  input {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.my-ul li label{
  background: red;
}
.my-ul input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li>
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox1">
      Item 1. Click me to change color.
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox2">
      Item 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changes color of `ul` instead it should change only for the clicked `li`

Comment: It changes only the two li. Try using inspect in your browser to see.

Comment: What I'm saying is that only the clicked `li` should change the color

Comment: @Tushar I have updated the example, it is now how you want it?

Comment: Yes, but not completely. Anyway, you've got idea. Try clicking on `Item 2`

Comment: If I update once more the code it would be the same as Vucko's first one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89044/discussion-between-vanntile-ianito-and-tushar).